# Question unanswered on MSE

Tags: discussion

Would a question that is not addressed in usual standard texts on a subject and which remains unanswered on MSE be on-topic on Mathoverflow?

Comment: It depends on the question!

Comment: Was concerned that maybe seen as asking allow level question, but perhaps can take a chance.

Comment: Hm? My point is that to be able to tell if the question is on-topic here or not you should tell us what the question is. How else can we tell?

Comment: Well, it's good that you ask, because it seems as if a lot of people suppose that if a question hasn't been answered at MSE, then it's time to ask it at MO. In many cases that's just not so, and I wish that more people would look around MO a little first, to get a sense of the place and see if MO would be a good fit for their questions before they ask.

Comment: @mariano:i agree , I should have given a link to the question.

Comment: @todd:some questions one does not get a satisfactory resolution; they continue to bother.

Comment: Sudhir: I understand. Of course you're welcome to try at MO -- we'll take a look -- but receiving an insufficient answer at MSE is not by itself a sufficient reason for keeping it open at MO.

Comment: @todd:thanks for that though I want to think carefully in the light of Andy's answer.iam sill trying to figure out why ' if in propositional calculus only a contradiction can tautologically imply an infinite number of sentence symbols, then how do we postulate the existence of precisely such a sentence in FOL' is not a clear enough question.Anyway the question is on MSE and if I feel more sure or more confident, I will venture into MO.

Answer (score 8):

If you are referring to the two questions that you asked on math.SE (namely [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547612/information-content-of-universal-sentence) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545229/relationship-between-propositional-and-first-order-logic)), then I don't think that either of them is appropriate for MO.  I think that they haven't been answered on math.SE largely because it is pretty unclear what you are asking, but it looks to me like both of them are questions about very elementary undergraduate logic, and thus would not be right here.

Comment: Oh well i jumped the gun. Let me see if I can delete the question.

Comment: Well, managed to delete the question here, though an answer still eludes me.i may also sayI did not find the question of information content of a mathematical axiom discussed particularly in any text book that I have read.